# Execution plan showing type conversion warning - ON Cond columns

Tags: sql-server

Getting Type conversion in Expression ..... may affect "CardinalityEstimate" in query pan choice.
The both tables T1 and T2 having clustered indexes.

How to overcome of warning?

```
CREATE TABLE T1
(
    KEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(50), 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    EXTERNAL_KEY VARCHAR(15),
    FLAG BIT
) 

INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS','DESC','NULL',0) 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS1','DESC','45213',1) 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS2','DESC','NULL',1) 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS3','DESC','NULL',0) 
INSERT INTO T1 VALUES(1,'ASS4','DESC','56321',1)

CREATE TABLE T2
(
    KEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(50), 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    EXTERNAL_KEY NUMERIC(14,0)
)

INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,'DSA','DESC',51256) 
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,'DSA1','DESC',45213) 
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,'DSA2','DESC',51256) 
INSERT INTO T2 VALUES(1,'DSA3','DESC',56321)
```

Actual Query:

```
SELECT T1.KEY,T1.FLAG,T2.KEY, FROM T2 INNER JOIN T1 ON 
CAST(NULLIF(RTRIM(T1.EXTERNAL_KEY),'') AS NUMERIC(14,0)) = T2.EXTERNAL_KEY
WHERE T1.EXTERNAL_KEY IS NOT NULL
```

Answer (score 1):

There are a few issues with your Sample data as well as the query. `KEY INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL` should be changed to  `[KEY]  NOT NULL` Or Do not insert into the Identity column `INSERT INTO T1 VALUES('ASS','DESC','NULL',0)` Also you are not inserting DB NULL but Text null when you enclosed 'NULL' with single quotes. for this. The below code should work

---

```
SELECT T1.[KEY],T1.FLAG,T2.[KEY]
FROM T2 
INNER JOIN T1 
ON NULLIF(T1.EXTERNAL_KEY ,'NULL')=T2.EXTERNAL_KEY 
WHERE T1.EXTERNAL_KEY IS NOT NULL
```

---

However I think you want NULL to be NULL and Not text so please change your insert from `INSERT INTO T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG) VALUES('ASS','DESC','NULL',0)`  to `INSERT INTO T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG) VALUES('ASS','DESC',NULL,0)

---

### Sample Data

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T1') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T1

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#T2') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #T2

CREATE TABLE #T1
(
    [KEY] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(50), 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    EXTERNAL_KEY VARCHAR(15),
    FLAG BIT
) 
GO

INSERT INTO #T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG) VALUES('ASS','DESC',NULL,0) 
INSERT INTO #T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG) VALUES('ASS1','DESC','45213',1) 
INSERT INTO #T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG)VALUES('ASS2','DESC',NULL,1) 
INSERT INTO #T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG)VALUES('ASS3','DESC',NULL,0) 
INSERT INTO #T1(CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY,FLAG)VALUES('ASS4','DESC','56321',1)

CREATE TABLE #T2
(
    [KEY] INT IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    CODE VARCHAR(50), 
    DESCRIPTION VARCHAR(100),
    EXTERNAL_KEY NUMERIC(14,0)
)
GO

INSERT INTO #T2 (CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY) VALUES('DSA','DESC',51256) 
INSERT INTO #T2 (CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY)VALUES('DSA1','DESC',45213) 
INSERT INTO #T2 (CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY)VALUES('DSA2','DESC',51256) 
INSERT INTO #T2 (CODE,DESCRIPTION,EXTERNAL_KEY)VALUES('DSA3','DESC',56321)
```

### Code

```
SELECT #T1.[KEY],#T1.FLAG,#T2.[KEY]
FROM #T2 
INNER JOIN #T1 
ON NULLIF(#T1.EXTERNAL_KEY ,NULL)=#T2.EXTERNAL_KEY 
WHERE #T1.EXTERNAL_KEY IS NOT NULL
```